# Creating an IEnumerable<Object> from custom property counts

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm going to apologize in advantage if this turns out a duplicate question, but I would have no clue as to how to find a solution to this.

In the current situation, there are certain objects called 'Requirement', listed in an IEnumerable<> of the the type 'Requirement' called Requirements, with different properties within them. In some method a list is generated from one of these properties and then grouped by the amount of occurence. This looks like:

```
this.AuthorList = this.Requirements.GroupBy(x => x.Author)
           .Select(x => string.Fortmat("{0} amount {1}", x.Key, x.Count()));
```

This also means the current IEnumerable is of the string type.

What I want to do, is have the {0} and {1} loosely put into 1 IEnumerable record, so I can extract them with a {Binding} in my view to properly align them, as to create a pleasent UI.

I figured I'd have to create some sort of new property, or put them in an List<>, but I'd have no idea where to find how I'd go around doing just that. Any help would be welcome.

Edited to hopefully create more clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your options here are numerous. You could use an anonymous type (though if you plan on using this data structure outside the executing method, you'll need to do something else):

```
...

.Select(x => new { Author = x.Key, Amount = x.Count() });

...
```

Or, you can use a `Tuple<String, Int32>` (though I'd advise against it if you want other people to actually be able to understand your code):

```
...

.Select(x => new Tuple<String,Int32>(x.Key, x.Count()));

...
```

Or, you can define a less generic data structure that more appropriately conveys the meaning of the information you're providing:

```
public class RequirementCount {

    public String Label { get; set; }

    public Int32 Count { get; set; }

}
```

Then just select that type:

```
...

.Select(x => new RequirementCount { Label = x.Key, Count = x.Count() });

...
```

Comment: As I have already 3 of these constructions that need this solution, which one would you say is most 'acceptable' within a plug-in application, as none of them seem really optimal? I'd assume creating 3 classes 'just to count' may be a bit overzealous, whereas the Tuple compromises the readability and the anontype won't reach to the view it needs to.

Comment: I'd say just use the Tuple and document it well. Possibly better (if your labels are unique) would be to use `.ToDictionary<String, Int32>` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new class to hold your data:

```
public class AuthorCount
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

And project to that:

```
AuthorList = this.Requirements.GroupBy(x => x.Author)
    .Select(x => new AuthorCount {Name = x.Key, Count = x.Count()})
    .ToList();
```

`AuthorList` now contains `IEnumerable<AuthorCount>` and you can bind to `Name` and `Count`.

Comment: If I were to choose to create the class to work around this, in a traditional MVVM construction, would I have to create this class (and thus each time I encounter this, another class) in a seperate VM?